# Avoiding infinite loop in simple Python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, infinite-loop

I have the following python 2.7 code, which calculates the number of coins needed to create `value`:

```
def find_change(value):
    if value < 0:
        return "Invalid value!"
    else:
        coins = 0
        while value > 0:
            num_quarters = value//.25
            coins += num_quarters
            value -= num_quarters*.25
            num_dimes = value//.1
            coins += num_dimes
            value -= num_dimes*.1
            num_nickels = value//.05
            coins += num_nickels
            value -= num_nickels*.05
            num_pennies = value//.01
            coins += num_pennies
            value -= num_pennies*.01
        return coins

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print find_change(.65)
```

I wanted a while loop so that the program would stop once the number of coins to create `value` was determined. However, running this program on my machine leads to an infinite loop since `value` never actually reaches zero but rather gets stuck at `1.38777878078e-17`.

How could I correct this code to prevent an infinite loop from occurring here?

Comment: Try using a single slash instead of a double slash, so `num_quarters = value / .25`. Also add an int operator.

Comment: You're dealing with change, which will only ever be integer values. You should convert the number of cents to an integer to start with, which will mean you never have to deal with floating point rounding issues.

Comment: There is no need for a while loop here

Comment: While it is possible to do this using floating-point arithmetic, it is error-prone and awkward to get it right.  It's much simpler to use integer arithmetic instead, and store pennies instead of dollars.